# Why the placement of \title makes a difference when using amsart with nag?

Tags: titles, capitalization, amsart, nag

```
% !TeX program = pdfLaTeX
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\title{The $n$-th term}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

If the `\title` command is placed after `\begin{document}`, as shown above, then the math mode n is capitalized. It is not capitalized if either `\title` is placed before `\begin{document}` or we do not use the `amsart` document class or the `l2tabu` option of the `nag` package. Why is that, and where should I put the `\title` by best practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`amsart` uses the macro `\uppercasenonmath` to prevent uppercasing of math characters. This could change the meaning of a variable, for example *n* could mean a number but *N* may be the name for a set.

The `nag` package makes the `$` sign an active character and uses it for syntax checks. In that case `\uppercasenonmath` simply doesn't work any more, so math letters within capitalized text can get capitalized too.

A good practice is to put the title after `\begin{document}`, so for example babel shortcuts would work within the title. Though such a package clash may require a workaround.